# Handling time stamps on a time series data and make prediction

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, deep-learning, lstm

So I have a data which looks like below;

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['16-08-2021', '16-08-2021', '17-08-2021', '18-08-2021', '19-08-2021'],
        'Reason no': ['R13', 'R2', 'R5', 'R2', 'R3'],
        'Minutes': [115, 625, 625, 1364, 1440],
        'Issues': ['Not meeting the hourly target output', 'Air leak issue', 'other problem', 'Air leak issue', 'Air leak issue']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]
we can see on 16-08-2021 we have 2 downtimes of different categories. so what we can do is modify this data into 2 separate time stamp. like '16-08-2021 1AM', '16-08-2021 4AM' and also assign time features to all other dates.
Minutes is the **downtime**, My goal is to forecast the next downtime for next 2 days (which can be like e.g

```
'Date': ['20-08-2021 5AM', '20-08-2021 6PM', '21-08-2021 12AM'],
        'Reason no': ['R5', 'R2', 'R2'],
        'Minutes': [655, 142, 425],
        'Issues': [ 'Air leak issue', 'other problem', 'Air leak issue']}
```

what i have seen is **most tutorial just treat datetime data as id and ignores it**, but in my case date and timestamp is an important tool. i want to train my model using LSTM and other hybrid technique.

So, How can I deal multiple data of same date using pandas and python. And keep date-time as a feature variable.
kindly looking for help. Thank you. Also looking for any additional insights and suggestions.

Comment: your `'Date'` column is not consistent between your example  and the oictured table. The time (e.g 1 AM) seems to be missing in all except the last date.

Comment: @Sandwichnick sorry sir, now i made it consistent.

Comment: @def__init__ have you considered retaining the date timestamp down to milliseconds? Or to feature engineer a composite column, which contains Date_Reason no to use in your model?

Comment: yeah i have considered feature encoding and normalizing our minutes using minmaxscalar. But i did all this by not considering date and time stamps. my goal is to take timestamp into account as well.